# Webdriver.io - Use selector to get all grand children?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, e2e, webdriver.io

Using webdriver.io....

For

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <td></td>
```

I can get all the `td` elements with `$$('td')`. But I can't with `$('table').$$('td')`. Instead I have to do `$('tbody').$$('td')`. Why is this? Or did I do something incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of webdriverIo is slightly different from selenium.

In webdriverIO `$('table').$$('td')` will check for direct child 'td under 'table', and as td is not a direct child it won't return anything.

instead, try:

```
$('table').$$(' td') (See if this works)
```

or

```
$$('table td')
```

Space in 'CSS' is similar to // in xpath

Better raise issue with webdriver io

Comment: `$$('table td')` worked